# PDO select results into variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm just switching to PDO from mysql, and having some issues.

I'm trying to do something that was immensely simple with mysql, all I want to do it save the result of my query into variables. I've trawled the interweb all day and every example is echoing or printing the results, whereas i need them in variables so I can then use them in the rest of my application.

I have a simple db table for storing points for where someone finishes. An id, the points to be allocated and the position of those points.

For example:

ID_1, 25, 1st

Theres only 5 rows in the table, 1st to 5th.

I want to have the points into variables like:

```
$point_1 = 25
$point_2 = 20
$point_3 = 18
$point_4 = 15
$point_5 = 10
```

This is the code im using:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM points";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
// here you go:
$points = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($points as $row) {

 print $row["point_position"] . "-" . $row["point_value"] ."<br/>";

}
```

But i want to get the values into variables? not print or echo them?

Comment: What have you tried specifically to create your variables? Why do you want the variables like this? Why don't you use an array?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Yeah...I really need a sleep now. Thanks :)

Comment: I need to use the values in many other places in the application.

Comment: You have the data in an array. If you need variables just take your array values and store them in variables. Where is the problem?

Comment: I dont know how to do that!

Comment: You've just done it. How can you not know how to do something you've just done?

Comment: OK, I'm just not getting it. If for example i wanted to use the value of 3rd place later on in my application, how would i do that? How would i access just the value of 3rd place with an array??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly this might help:

```
$result = array();

foreach ( $points as $i => $row ) {
    $result[$i] = $row;
}
```

Now each row from the query is at their unique position in the $result array. Mind the iterator variable, $i, compared to your foreach loop.

Comment: this is not working for me! I need the values to be accessible on their own? I dont get how i would access the array on the fly for the individual values? How would i access the value of 3rd place with the above code?

Comment: Let's say you want the 4th column on the 7th row. Then you do this $result[6][4];

Answer (score -1):

Try to associate query result to an associative array